# LINQ query for this scenario

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, ienumerable, ilist

I have these 2 interfaces:

```
public interface IShipment
{
    IEnumerable<IShippedItem> Contents { get; }
    string InvoiceNumber { get; }
}

public interface IShippedItem
{
    string ProductCode { get; }
    int Quantity { get; }
}
```

Now, I am trying to write a `LINQ` statement to get me just a list of `ProductCode`.

How to go about this?

```
IEnumerable<IShipment> shipments = GetShipments();
var productCodeList = from shipment in shipment
                      ???????
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to flatten your contents then just use `Select` and get the `ProductCode` for each `IShippedItem`.

```
var productCodes = shipments
                   .SelectMany(x => x.Contents)
                   .Select(x => x.ProductCode)
                   .ToList();
```

Answer (score -2):

My fault, I submitted to early, here it is:

```
from shipment in shipments 
from shippedItem in shipment.Contents  
select shippedItem.ProductCode
```